# Missing dependency while upgrading AEM 6.5.1 to 6.5.10

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

I am upgrading `AEM 6.5.1` (Service pack 1) to `AEM 6.5.10` (Service pack 10). For this I installed SP10 in AEM as well updated the `uber-jar` version to 6.5.10 in my source code `POM.xml` file.
I see that in the OSGI console, my bundle is in `Installed` and not `Active` state. This is because certain dependencies (which before the update were not present) are missing. I have been able to get those dependencies, except one.

```
com.microsoft.schemas.office.powerpoint -- Cannot be resolved
```

I am unable to find any JARs online that fixes this issue. I tried Apache POI but no success. Does anyone know what this dependency is and where I can get it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try the Adobe Granite POI wrapper to see if it fixes the issue? - https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.adobe.granite/com.adobe.granite.poi/2.0.8/bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using it at all, you can exclude it.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <!-- Import any version of javax.inject, to allow running on multiple versions of AEM -->
            <Import-Package>
                javax.inject;version=0.0.0,
                !sun.misc;resolution=optional,!javax.persistence,!com.sun.jdi.*,
                !com.microsoft.schemas.office.powerpoint,*
            </Import-Packages>
```